# How do I see detailed Rails logs in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, stdout

I would like to see the same logs in Heroku that I see when I execute `heroku logs -t` in the terminal. At one point this logic in the environment config files produced those logs in the Heroku web dashboard. This is what the [Getting Started on Heroku with Rails 5.x](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) link from the Heroku website says to do.

```
if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
  logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
  logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
end
```

Now when I go into Heroku I see the default logging like I saw when I first started using Heroku.

I read this section before from this [Heroku link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging).

Some frameworks send log output somewhere other than stdout by default. These might require extra configuration. For example, when using the Ruby on Rails TaggedLogger by ActiveSupport, you should add the following into your app’s configuration to get stdout logging:

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

It's not clear to me how I should change my config files to get this working as before.

Comment: By "in Heroku", you mean in Heroku's web dashboard?

Comment: Yes. I will update my description. Thanks @Chris!

Comment: `heroku logs` and the log output in the Heroku dashboard should come from the same source (though there may be a delay in the web dashboard). Are you seeing meaningfully different output, or just a delay?

Comment: heroku logs -t gives me detailed Rails logging in the terminal but I don't see the same logging in the Heroku web dashboard. I did something long ago to see the detail Rails logging in the Heroku web dashboard. I don't know if the issue is related to me upgrading from Rails 5.0 to 5.1. That's the only change I can think of that may have changed something. It's been many months since I updated my Rails applications.

Comment: @Chris I posted this question after restarting dynos two or three times. I just viewed my logs again and it appears they are working now.